# missing $ inserted error for eqnarray

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations

I get the missing $ inserted error(and many other errors like "missing } inserted") for the following code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,oneside,onecolumn]{article}

    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{verbatim}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{eqnarray}

    f(x)&=&\cos x\\
    f'(x)&=&-\sin x\\
    \int_0^xf(y)\ud y&=&\sin x

    \end{eqnarray}

    \end{document}
```

I have tried out different changes based on Googling for this error, but nothing seems to help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: You can't have empty lines in an `eqnarray` environment. Just remove the empty first and last line and things should compile provided you have defined `\ud` somewhere in your preamble. But as samcarter hints at, you should if at all possible avoid `eqnarray` and use `align` (the same thing about empty lines applies: they are not allowed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have blank lines inside the `eqnarray` environment.  Note also the use of `\dd` from the `physics` package.  Besides, as indicated by @samcarter, `align` should be preferred.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{physics}% for the differential operator \dd


\begin{document}

Using \texttt{eqnarray},
\begin{eqnarray}
  f(x)  &=& \cos x\\
  f'(x) &=& -\sin x\\
  \int_0^x f(y)\dd{y} &=& \sin x                       
\end{eqnarray}
and better, using \texttt{align},
\begin{align}
  f(x)  &= \cos x\\
  f'(x) &= -\sin x\\
  \int_0^x f(y)\dd{y} &= \sin x                       
\end{align}

\end{document}
```